# Navigation - mouseover show / hide submenus - problems using CSS / JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, menu

I have a vertical side menu and the submenus flyout to the right of the menu items on mouseover.

The main problem is the submenu items are difficult to select due to the distance/position from the main menu item.

Another issue is sometimes submenus still show when they shouldn't.

This was originally written as a click event and worked perfectly but now the client wants it to work on hover.

How can I make this work nicely, please?

You can see it in action here:  https://codepen.io/lol4000/pen/VwMLOMO

The main code:

```jQuery
$('.nav li > .subnav').parent().hover(function() {
var submenu = $(this).children('.subnav');
if ( $(submenu).is(':hidden') ) {
    $(submenu).show(200);
} else {
    $(submenu).hide(200);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding another answer. Now the lists are aligned. You can increase the hidden time.

```js
$('#menu_toggle').click(function() {
  $(".nav_list").toggle();
  var nav2 = $('#nav-bar2').hasClass("show_nav2");
  $(".subnav").toggle();
  //adjust subnav position as well
  $('.subnav').toggleClass('expanded');

  $('#canvas').toggleClass("canvas");
  $('#nav-bar').toggleClass("show_nav");
  if (nav2) {
    $('#nav-bar2').removeClass("show_nav2");
    $('#canvas').removeClass("canvas");
    $('#canvas').removeClass("canvas2");
  }
});



$('#nav_link_formations').click(function() {
  $('#canvas').toggleClass("canvas");
  $('#canvas').toggleClass("canvas2");
  $('#nav-bar').addClass("show_nav");
  $('#nav-bar2').toggleClass("show_nav2");
});


//show submenu faster
$('.nav li > .subnav').parent().mouseenter(function() {
  let submenu = $(this).children('.subnav');
  $(submenu).css({
    transform: "scaleY(1)",
    transitionDuration: ".3s",
    opacity: "1"
  });
});

//take time to hide
$('.nav li > .subnav').parent().mouseleave(function() {
  let submenu = $(this).children('.subnav');
  $(submenu).css({
    transform: "scaleY(0)",
    transitionDuration: "2.0s",
    opacity: "0"
  });
});

//quickly expand it when user hovers over sub menu
$('.nav li > .subnav').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).css({
    transform: "scaleY(1)",
    transitionDuration: "0s"
  });
});
$('.nav li > .subnav').parent().hover(function() {
  var submenu = $(this).children('.subnav');
  if ($(submenu).is(':hidden')) {
    $(submenu).show(500);
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

#news_toggle {
  width: 68px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left
}

#news-sidebar {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: #fff;
}

#sidebar-nav {
  width: 160px;
}

#canvas {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  transition: .5s;
  padding-left: calc(282px + 2rem);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rebeccapurple;
}

#menu_toggle {
  color: lightblue;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer
}

.l-navbar {
  float: left;
  left: 68px;
  width: 68px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 0 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.l-navbar2 {
  float: left;
  left: -30%;
  width: 224px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: .5rem 1rem 0 0;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: -10;
}

#nav-bar2 {
  z-index: -99999;
}

.nav {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-left: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.nav_link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 1rem;
}

.nav_link {
  position: relative;
  color: rebeccapurple;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  transition: .3s
}

.nav_icon {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.show_nav {
  width: 224px;
}

.show_nav2 {
  left: 292px;
}

.show_sidebar {
  left: 0 !important;
}

.canvas {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  transition: .5s;
  left: calc(360px + 2rem);
}

.fas {
  color: lightblue
}

.active {
  color: rebeccapurple;
}

.active::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.height-100 {
  height: 100vh
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  margin-left: 0
}

nav .subnav {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
  display: hidden;
  new attributes left: 0px !important;
  margin-left: 10rem;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0.0;
  transform: scaleY(0.0);
  /* transition-duration: .5s; */
  /* transition-property: transform, opacity; */
  /* transition-timing-function: ease-out; */
}


/*new rule*/

nav .expanded .subnav {
  left: 100px !important;
}

.nav_list {
  display: none;
  z-index: 4000;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 90000;
}

.subnav>ul {
  /* padding-left: 300px; */
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row flex-nowrap">

        <div id="offcanvas" class="col-auto px-0">


          <div id="news-sidebar" class="collapse collapse-horizontal min-vh-100">
            <div class="news-content">
              news news news
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="maincontent" class="col-auto px-0">

          <div id="news_toggle" data-bs-target="#news-sidebar" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="min-vh-100">NEWS</div>

          <div class="l-navbar" id="nav-bar">
            <div id="menu_toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> </div>

            <nav class="nav">
              <div>
                <div class="nav_list">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#" class="nav_link active" id="nav_link_formations"> <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i>
                        <span class="nav_name">Formations</span> </a>

                      <ul class="subnav">
                        <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i>
                        <span class="nav_name">Formations</span>
                        <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link active">Formations 1</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Formations 2</a> </li>
                      </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-user nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Users</span> </a>
                      <ul class="subnav">
                        <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link active">Users 1</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Users 2</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Users 3</a> </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-message-square-detail nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Messages</span> </a>
                      <ul class="subnav">
                        <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link active">Messages 1</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Messages 2</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Messages 3</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Messages 4</a> </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-bookmark nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Bookmark</span> </a>
                      <ul class="subnav">
                        <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link active">Bookmark 1</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Bookmark 2</a> </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>

                </div>
            </nav>
            </div>



            <span class="l-navbar2" id="nav-bar2">
            [LOGO]
          </span>

            <div id="canvas">


              <div class="height-100 bg-light">
                <h1>Homepage</h1>
                <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
                survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
                desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

                <h2>Why do we use it?</h2>
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
                content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
                Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>

  </html>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is working much better. Thankyou

Comment: One more thing, I hope you understand. You were saying to another person in comments that the submenus show and hide at "weird" times. The reason that was occurring is that you were not hiding and showing the element nav rather you were just trying to hide it under the logo banner. So what was happening was your navlinks were just under the logo banner when you thought they were hidden. And whenever the user's mouse passed over the logo the submenus would appear. What I did was added a `display:hidden` in the nav. So when the user clicks they would appear and hide when the user clicks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the submenu slowly so that user can catch it. Once user catches it expand it instantly.

```js
$('#menu_toggle').click(function() {

  var nav2 = $('#nav-bar2').hasClass("show_nav2");

  //adjust subnav position as well
  $('.subnav').toggleClass('expanded');

  $('#canvas').toggleClass("canvas");
  $('#nav-bar').toggleClass("show_nav");
  if (nav2) {
    $('#nav-bar2').removeClass("show_nav2");
    $('#canvas').removeClass("canvas");
    $('#canvas').removeClass("canvas2");
  }
});


$('#nav_link_formations').click(function() {
  $('#canvas').toggleClass("canvas");
  $('#canvas').toggleClass("canvas2");
  $('#nav-bar').addClass("show_nav");
  $('#nav-bar2').toggleClass("show_nav2");
});


//show submenu faster
$('.nav li > .subnav').parent().mouseenter(function() {
  let submenu = $(this).children('.subnav');
  $(submenu).css({
    transform: "scaleY(1)",
    transitionDuration: ".3s",
    opacity: "1"
  });
});

//take time to hide
$('.nav li > .subnav').parent().mouseleave(function() {
  let submenu = $(this).children('.subnav');
  $(submenu).css({
    transform: "scaleY(0)",
    transitionDuration: "1.0s",
    opacity: "0"
  });
});

//quickly expand it when user hovers over sub menu
$('.nav li > .subnav').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).css({
    transform: "scaleY(1)",
    transitionDuration: "0s"
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#news_toggle {
  width: 68px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left
}

#news-sidebar {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: #fff;
}

#sidebar-nav {
  width: 160px;
}

#canvas {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  transition: .5s;
  padding-left: calc(282px + 2rem);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rebeccapurple;
}

#menu_toggle {
  color: lightblue;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer
}

.l-navbar {
  float: left;
  left: 68px;
  width: 68px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 0 0;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: 100
}

.l-navbar2 {
  float: left;
  left: -30%;
  width: 224px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: .5rem 1rem 0 0;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: 90
}

.nav {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav_link {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem 0 .5rem 1.5rem
}

.nav_link {
  position: relative;
  color: rebeccapurple;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  transition: .3s
}

.nav_icon {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.show_nav {
  width: 224px;
}

.show_nav2 {
  left: 292px;
}

.show_sidebar {
  left: 0 !important;
}

.canvas {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  transition: .5s;
  left: calc(360px + 2rem);
}

.fas {
  color: lightblue
}

.active {
  color: rebeccapurple;
}

.active::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple
}

.height-100 {
  height: 100vh
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  margin-left: 0
}

nav .subnav {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
  display: block;
  
  /*new attributes*/
  left: 140px !important;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  opacity: 0.0;
  transform: scaleY(0.0);
  transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}


/*new rule*/

nav .expanded.subnav {
  left: 300px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex-nowrap">

    <div id="offcanvas" class="col-auto px-0">


      <div id="news-sidebar" class="collapse collapse-horizontal min-vh-100">
        <div class="news-content">
          news news news
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="maincontent" class="col-auto px-0">

      <div id="news_toggle" data-bs-target="#news-sidebar" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="min-vh-100">NEWS</div>

      <div class="l-navbar" id="nav-bar">
        <div id="menu_toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> </div>

        <nav class="nav">
          <div>
            <div class="nav_list">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="nav_link active" id="nav_link_formations"> <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i>
                    <span class="nav_name">Formations</span> </a>
                  <ul class="subnav">
                    <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i>
                    <span class="nav_name">Formations</span>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link active">Formations 1</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Formations 2</a> </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-user nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Users</span> </a>
                  <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link active">Users 1</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Users 2</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Users 3</a> </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-message-square-detail nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Messages</span> </a>
                  <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link active">Messages 1</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Messages 2</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Messages 3</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Messages 4</a> </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-bookmark nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Bookmark</span> </a>
                  <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link active">Bookmark 1</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Bookmark 2</a> </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

            </div>
        </nav>
        </div>



        <div class="l-navbar2" id="nav-bar2">
          [LOGO]
        </div>

        <div id="canvas">


          <div class="height-100 bg-light">
            <h1>Homepage</h1>
            <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
            survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
            publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

            <h2>Why do we use it?</h2>
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
            content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
            Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've modified `nav .subnav` CSS rule. And, in javascript, instead of hover used mouseenter and mouseleave functions. And added mouseenter handler for `.subnav` as well. You can play with transition times to make it more user friendly.


Also, when main nav is collapsed you need to bring subnave closer. See use of new `nav .expanded.subnav` CSS rule in javascript code.

Comment: Thankyou for th ein depth answer, however the example does not seem to work well to be honest.  Its still veyr difficult to select the sub menus and keeps hiding / showing at wierd times.

Comment: What do you mean by "weird times"? I've used `skaleY` for the show/hide effect for the demo. You can use combinations of `width, height, scaleX, translate etc` for the reveal. For example change height from 0%-100% to show the submenu..

Comment: I need the sub menus to remain open instead of closing when I move the mouse towards the sub menu

Comment: Also Im not sure of the benefit of replacing the JQuery show / hide to the transform?  the speed of the show hide can be adjusted so I dont underdstand this change.

Comment: What I mean is, how do I keep the submenu open whilst moving from the active li:a tag on mouseover to the submenu?  It still keeps closing.  IThe last mouseenter function you provided has improved it slightly but Im not sure what benefit the other changes have made?  Hope that makes sense. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you wanted. You were hiding your nav under the logo div. What you should have done is to set the display property of your nav to none and then toggle it so that every time the user clicks on the menu button the nav shows up and when the user clicks the button again it hides. Now I have done most of the things that I assume you wanted. For the hiding and repeating of subnavs, you now have the idea of how to do it. I have aligned the subnavs, I just don't know jQuery, otherwise, I would've done that too. I have commented out the extra CSS properties so you can check out what was causing the issue.

```js
$('#menu_toggle').click(function() {
  $(".nav_list").toggle();
  var nav2 = $('#nav-bar2').hasClass("show_nav2");
  $(".subnav").toggle();
  //adjust subnav position as well
  $('.subnav').toggleClass('expanded');

  $('#canvas').toggleClass("canvas");
  $('#nav-bar').toggleClass("show_nav");
  if (nav2) {
    $('#nav-bar2').removeClass("show_nav2");
    $('#canvas').removeClass("canvas");
    $('#canvas').removeClass("canvas2");
  }
});



$('#nav_link_formations').click(function() {
  $('#canvas').toggleClass("canvas");
  $('#canvas').toggleClass("canvas2");
  $('#nav-bar').addClass("show_nav");
  $('#nav-bar2').toggleClass("show_nav2");
});


//show submenu faster
$('.nav li > .subnav').parent().mouseenter(function() {
  let submenu = $(this).children('.subnav');
  $(submenu).css({
    transform: "scaleY(1)",
    transitionDuration: ".3s",
    opacity: "1"
  });
});

//take time to hide
$('.nav li > .subnav').parent().mouseleave(function() {
  let submenu = $(this).children('.subnav');
  $(submenu).css({
    transform: "scaleY(0)",
    transitionDuration: "1.0s",
    opacity: "0"
  });
});

//quickly expand it when user hovers over sub menu
$('.nav li > .subnav').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).css({
    transform: "scaleY(1)",
    transitionDuration: "0s"
  });
});
$('.nav li > .subnav').parent().hover(function() {
var submenu = $(this).children('.subnav');
if ( $(submenu).is(':hidden') ) {
    $(submenu).show(200);
} else {
    $(submenu).hide(200);
}
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

#news_toggle {
  width: 68px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left
}

#news-sidebar {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: #fff;
}

#sidebar-nav {
  width: 160px;
}

#canvas {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  transition: .5s;
  padding-left: calc(282px + 2rem);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rebeccapurple;
}

#menu_toggle {
  color: lightblue;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer
}

.l-navbar {
  float: left;
  left: 68px;
  width: 68px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 0 0;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: 100
}

.l-navbar2 {
  float: left;
  left: -30%;
  width: 224px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: .5rem 1rem 0 0;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: 90
}

.nav {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* .nav_link {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem 0 .5rem 1.5rem
} */

.nav_link {
  position: relative;
  color: rebeccapurple;
  /* margin-bottom: 1.5rem; */
  transition: .3s
}

.nav_icon {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.show_nav {
  width: 224px;
}

.show_nav2 {
  left: 292px;
}

.show_sidebar {
  left: 0 !important;
}

.canvas {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  transition: .5s;
  left: calc(360px + 2rem);
}

.fas {
  color: lightblue
}

.active {
  color: rebeccapurple;
}

.active::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple
}

.height-100 {
  height: 100vh
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  margin-left: 0
}

nav .subnav {
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* z-index: 99999; */
  display: hidden;
  /*new attributes*/
  /* left: 140px !important; */
  /* margin-left: -4.5rem; */
  opacity: 0.0;
  transform: scaleY(0.0);
  transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out; 
}


/*new rule*/

nav .expanded.subnav {
  /* left: 300px !important; */
}

.nav_list {
  display: none;
}

ul>.subnav {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">

      <div id="offcanvas" class="col-auto px-0">


        <div id="news-sidebar" class="collapse collapse-horizontal min-vh-100">
          <div class="news-content">
            news news news
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="maincontent" class="col-auto px-0">

        <div id="news_toggle" data-bs-target="#news-sidebar" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="min-vh-100">NEWS</div>

        <div class="l-navbar" id="nav-bar">
          <div id="menu_toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> </div>

          <nav class="nav">
            <div>
              <div class="nav_list">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav_link active" id="nav_link_formations"> <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i>
                      <span class="nav_name">Formations</span> </a>
                    <ul class="subnav">
                      <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i>
                      <span class="nav_name">Formations</span>
                      <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link active">Formations 1</a> </li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Formations 2</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-user nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Users</span> </a>
                    <ul class="subnav">
                      <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link active">Users 1</a> </li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Users 2</a> </li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Users 3</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-message-square-detail nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Messages</span> </a>
                    <ul class="subnav">
                      <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link active">Messages 1</a> </li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Messages 2</a> </li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Messages 3</a> </li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Messages 4</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-bookmark nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Bookmark</span> </a>
                    <ul class="subnav">
                      <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link active">Bookmark 1</a> </li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="sub_nav_link ">Bookmark 2</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>

              </div>
          </nav>
          </div>



          <div class="l-navbar2" id="nav-bar2">
            [LOGO]
          </div>

          <div id="canvas">


            <div class="height-100 bg-light">
              <h1>Homepage</h1>
              <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
              survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
              desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

              <h2>Why do we use it?</h2>
              It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
              content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
              Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I need the submenu to show at the right hand side of the parent item, not underneath, therefore it should show in the grey column  underneath the logo.  Also can I ask ahy you have used the transform to show and hide the submenu as opposed to what I had originally?  I dont see the benefit of this?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't explicitly mentioned whether you wanted the submenus on the right. I thought that distance was the problem and so I placed them underneath. I have fixed this in my new answer. Using transform just makes the show and hide transition smoothly. Transform doesn't alter the show and hide behavior, it is you can say icing on the cake. Without it the submenus will show and hide in an "instantaneous" manner. If you want to remove it you can and it will have no effect on hide and show.

Answer (score -1):

Can you do it on click:

```
$('.nav li > .subnav').parent().click(function() {
    var submenu = $(this).children('.subnav');
    if ( $(submenu).is(':hidden') ) {
        $(submenu).show(200);
    } else {
        $(submenu).hide(200);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes I know that, it was originally a click but the client wants hover as the main link does not have a page

Comment: This doesn't really "clean anything up" their issue is with CSS.